# NSDateFormatter returns 1970 instead of current year with format MM/dd

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

The following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
NSDate *newTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10/01"];
```

sets the resulting date to 10/01/1970.  Is there a "right" way to have the formatter assume that you mean a date in the current year, or closest to the present date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `[dateFormatter setLenient:YES]`?

Comment: perfect, don't know how I missed that.  Thank you.